How can I ensure that multiple instances of my Spring Integration application do not process the same SFTP file simultaneously?
I am using Spring Integration for file transfer, Spring Batch for processing, and Spring Integration again to mark files as done. My setup includes:

JdbcMetadataStore for metadata storage

SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter and SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter for file filtering

PostgreSQL as the database


Despite this setup, I am encountering issues where multiple instances end up grabbing the same file, causing the entire flow to break. I need a solution to distribute the files across instances without synchronization issues, possibly by implementing some sort of locking mechanism.
I have tried using both fixed delay and cron scheduling, but I do not want this application to fail in production because of this issue.
Any advice or best practices to handle this scenario would be greatly appreciated.
Spring Integration Flow:
IntegrationFlow.from(
                    Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory)
                            .remoteDirectory(".")
                            .deleteRemoteFiles(false)
                            .filter(remoteFileFilter)
                            .localDirectory(new File(localDirectory))
                            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                            .maxFetchSize(1),
                    configurer -> configurer.poller(Pollers.cron("some-cron-here")
                            .advice(rotatingServerAdvice)))
            .transform(transformerService, "toJobLaunchRequest")
            .channel(jobLaunchingChannel)
            .get();

Error Stacktrace (using 'transactional()'):
2024-09-13T10:50:02.499-04:00 ERROR 16323 --- [some-service] [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing '/remote-file-path' to local directory
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:345)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:266)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:47)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.integration.aop.ReceiveMessageAdvice.invoke(ReceiveMessageAdvice.java:56)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy118.receive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:220)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:450)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy117.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:419)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:355)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:56)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:54)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:459)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:338)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT METADATA_VALUE FROM INT_METADATA_STORE
WHERE METADATA_KEY=? AND REGION=?
]; SQL state [25P02]; error code [0]; ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:723)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:754)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:767)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:889)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:916)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.metadata.JdbcMetadataStore.putIfAbsent(JdbcMetadataStore.java:230)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:355)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:379)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:768)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.metadata.JdbcMetadataStore$$SpringCGLIB$$0.putIfAbsent(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.accept(AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter.accept(ChainFileListFilter.java:68)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.transferFilesFromRemoteToLocal(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:374)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.lambda$synchronizeToLocalDirectory$0(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:339)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:450)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2733)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2420)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:372)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:517)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:137)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:732)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "int_metadata_store_pk"
  Detail: Key (metadata_key, region)=(remote:SimpleTestFile (94).txt, DEFAULT) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2733)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2420)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:372)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:517)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$update$2(JdbcTemplate.java:975)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:658)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.metadata.JdbcMetadataStore.tryToPutIfAbsent(JdbcMetadataStore.java:241)
    at org.springframework.integration.jdbc.metadata.JdbcMetadataStore.putIfAbsent(JdbcMetadataStore.java:222)
    ... 63 more


https://www.baeldung.com/shedlock-spring

We may need to know more about your application. Perhaps you use an SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource which is based on a local dir. And when you run several instances of your application locally, they all may just look into the same local dir. So, even if only one of your adapters is synchronizing to that local dir, the rest instances just simply see local files. Consider to setup localFileListFilter with a respective FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter based on DB. Or use different local dirs. OR if I'm wrong, share some simple project to reproduce.

official github: https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock

@JorgeCampos Thanks I will take a looks at that library.

@ArtemBilan I wish I could share the code but I use Sftp.inboundAdapter DSL with SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter and SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter. It works fine with RedisMetadataStore down to same second polling. It fails with JdbcMetadataStore. It picks up the same file and/or clashes with other instances trying to grab that same file.

@ArtemBilan The batch process fails when the same file is picked because the job would exist. Let me know if you have more questions regarding the approach

@ArtemBilan Also, the solution will be deployed on a cloud service with atleast six instances running at the same time. Do you have any suggestion to handle the synchronicity and why would it work with Redis?

Try with transaction() on the poller. I don't ask you to share the whole code, but something simple what we could run on our side to reproduce. Definitely you target project has a lot of logic not related to the problem. So, better to assist us with as little code as possible, so we would be able to digest it easy.

@ArtemBilan Thats a good idea, I will try that. I have added the code sample to the question above. Let me know if that works.

@ArtemBilan I am using ChainFileListFilter<SftpClient.DirEntry> to combine SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter and SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.

Yeah... See if wrapping poller to the transactional() helps.

With transactional(), I am getting org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "int_metadata_store_pk"

@ArtemBilan I forgot to tag you

The error is correct when several instance are trying to insert the record for the same file. That's exactly a logic we are expecting from the JdbcMetadataStore.putIfAbsent(). However looks like that PostgreSQL error does not translate to the DataIntegrityViolationException we are catching over there. Would you mind to share the whole stack trace in your question together with Spring Integration version?

@ArtemBilan I have added the stacktrace and Spring Integration version is 6.3.3

OK. This is something to do with PostgreSQL configuration. current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block which is not OK for the logic we have so far. The INSERT failure must not rollback our transaction. Are you sure that you that JdbcMetadataStore is configured as a bean and you have @EnableTransactionManagement ? That's why I asked for a simple project to reproduce.

@ArtemBilan Yes, I have ConcurrentMetadataStore bean which is configured like this:
@Bean public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore(DataSource dataSource) {return new JdbcMetadataStore(dataSource);}


I also have @EnableTransactionManagement. Strange thing is it works with Redis, I was expecting same behaviour with Jdbc.

Redis is not transactional. I would suggest you to try with other JDBC vendor. That transaction rollback not suppose to happen since transaction is in hand of application, not PostgreSQL by itself.

@ArtemBilan, I will give a try and let you know

@ArtemBilan I tried it with MariaDB and I am getting below exception:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: (conn=630) Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.CannotAcquireLockException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO INT_METADATA_STORE(METADATA_KEY, METADATA_VALUE, REGION)
SELECT ?, ?, ?
FROM INT_METADATA_STORE
WHERE METADATA_KEY=? AND REGION=?

The JdbcMetadataStore comes with a setLockHint() option. See its JavaDocs and perhaps adjust respectively.

@ArtemBilan It worked three times in row and I thought finally its done but when I ran again with 7 instances with 7 remote files, it failed again with same deadlock exception.
What would you recommend in terms of designing these type of apps, where we process files with multiple instances and can avoid clashes in terms of grabbing the files?

The solution you chose with this JdbcMetadataStore is correct, but apparently something else needs to be done to satisfy this or that RDBMS vendor.

Let's see if setLockHint("for update skip locked") helps!

@ArtemBilan I tried with lock hint and it worked three times and then fourth failed again

That’s because there was no a race condition in those first times - got lucky. I’ll try to write a test tomorrow against PosgreSQL and MySQL. Perhaps the one against Derby and H2 is not enough to cover all the real DB use-cases… stay with Redis for now

@ArtemBilan yes I will be using redis for now and later change it to db. Let me know how the test goes.

So, yeah. I have reproduced it and apparently that HAVING COUNT(*)=0 does not work well for Postgres and it does rollback the whole transaction on failure. So, we have to make some other fix into this JdbcMetadataStore. Probably fully different fix to support MariaDB, too...

I checked with redis too, multiple instances seem to pick up same file and fail in spring batch job (job already exist exception). I am very confused why it was working before (maybe got lucky). It good that you found something, seems like we need a good way to sync files between multiple instances.

The job already exist exception might be for some other reason. For example, you have started it before and its record is still in DB.

I recreated the entire schema, it seems that the redis metadata store accepts the file as a duplicate. Is there any locking in Redis Metadata Store with Sftp Persistent File List Filter?

There is the logic in the AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter which does check for modified attribute of the file. So, even if same file name is used, but with different modified value, then the entry in DB is overridden and such a file coming down to the channel adapter for processing. I think that is a different story and we need to look into that in the separate SO thread.

Yes I will check and confirm this one tomorrow

We have confirmed that this is a bug in Spring Integration and it has a fix for this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9481.
The releases for 6.2.9, 6.3.4 and 6.4.0-M3 are going to happen today.
The problem is that PostgreSQL rollbacks transaction in case of query failure.
In our case we have to add ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING for the INSERT operation.
In case of MySQL-based vendors, we receive CannotAcquireLockException instead of DataIntegrityViolationException. So, that one is included into the logic as well.

The solution works well. Thank you for making the change. I see below warning messing being printed multiple times:
2024-09-19T16:11:09.010-04:00  WARN 49243 --- [some-app] [ck-leadership-1] o.m.jdbc.message.server.ErrorPacket      : Error: 1062-23000: Duplicate entry 'c444858e-0aae-3727-9a73-d2eae62321ad-DEFAULT' for key 'PRIMARY'
Do you what this means or is it related to this change? I also have leader election in my project which will assign a leader to recover stuck files.

That warning comes from the MariaDB driver. Not my change. They just throw something what is converted to the CannotAcquireLockException and that one we handle on Spring Integration side.
